# Communication Technique used in Commercial Vehicle Tracking Systems

Tags: communication, tracking

I am working on a vehicle tracking system that conveys the coordinates information from the vehicle to a server via GPRS communication. For this purpose I am using a GSM module with an arduino uno.
As I was working on this I wondered as to which technique is used in commercial vehicle tracking systems.
Which communication methodology is used in commercial vehicle tracking systems? (Is it GPRS, WCDMA or something else?

Comment: So, what have you found - what do Mercedes use for example?

Comment: They generally use the common cellphone system in the region.

Answer (score 1):

Most vehicle tracking companies use the cellphone network available in the country (i.e GPRS).

For example, using a very cheap GSM module like SIM800, one communicates with the server using a TCP/IP (search WebSockets). This is a common practice. I've seen teardowns of [Automatic](https://www.automatic.com/), [CarSense](https://www.carsense.in/) and others.

For Automatic's teardown go to [link](https://medium.com/ruki-founder-s-journal/automatic-teardown-4cfa80cbf5f5).